# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' on 2 intergers

Tags: c#

I am making a program for calculating the cost of 3d printing stuff. i came up on this question.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double getal1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double getal2 = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        double volume = 0.002405281875;
        double volume1 = 0;
        int dichtheidpla = Int32.Parse("1,24");


        if (comboBox1.Text == "PLA")
        {
            //volume berekenen
            volume1 = volume * getal1;
            V.Text = volume1.ToString("N2");

            //gewicht berekenen


            int volumeberekend = Convert.ToInt32(volume1);
            gewicht1.Text = volumeberekend * dichtheidpla;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "ABS")
        {

        }

    }
}
```

when i want to calculate gewicht1 the error shows me: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'. there is a red line under 'volumeberekend * dichtheidpla'.

Comment: 1,24 does not look like an Int.

Comment: For some culture (i.e fr-FR), it is.

Comment: You're performing math, multiplying two `int` types and trying to store that result in a  `string`. C# is a fairly strongly-typed language and you can't just mix and match types without a conversion.

Comment: @FrancoisB it still won't be an integer even if `,` is the decimal separator.  It has decimals!

Comment: Yep... That explains my poor math grades!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gewicht1.Text` is an string type, and the result of the expression will be an `int`. So you just have to convert that result into `string`.

```
gewicht1.Text = (volumeberekend * dichtheidpla).ToString();
```

Comment: when i try to run it i get an error on this line: 
int dichtheidpla = Int32.Parse("1,24");
FormatException was unhandled.

Comment: @ThijnLinders that is because `1,24` is not an integer. Remove the` ,` and it'll run perfectly

Comment: but how can i get 1,24 then?

Comment: Why do you want `1,24` to be an integer?

Comment: i need that number to calculate with.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't get why do you want that `,` in a number? Is it actually `124` or `1.24`?

Comment: If you have a decimal containing value, you can use `float`,`double`,`decimal`. They have larger capacity than each other respectively. If you few digit value, you use `float`

Answer (score 0):

It's as it says, it can't implicitly convert `int` to `string` without you deciding how you want that to happen.

Try this explicit conversion instead:

```
int volumeberekend = Convert.ToInt32(volume1);
int total = volumeberekend * dichtheidpla
gewicht1.Text = total.ToString();
```